# Youtube videos on top of content on iOS only (iPad/iPhone)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, youtube, z-index

My problem is simple:

- I have a youtube video embedded in my page
- I have a login modal that should show up when performing some action

On desktop everything's fine, but on iPad, the login modal is hidden behind the youtube video.

The common solution I've found:

```
<param name="wmode" value="opaque">
```

does not work on iOS (because it's not using the flash version I guess).

I tried using both `object` and `iframe` to embed the video, but none of them works.

Any ideas?